# Can two Gateway workers publish throttle data to one traffic manager node

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are having a gateway cluster with 2 nodes. Can both these nodes publish data to same traffic manager node or do we need to have 2 traffic manager nodes for each? How should be the configuration if we could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can have a single traffic manager node for two/multiple gateways.

Have a look at https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Deployment+Patterns#DeploymentPatterns-Pattern3